# Random p tag to display

Tags: javascript

I am trying to revert back to some work I have done where I have used jQuery. I would like to use vanilla JS instead. I have commented out the working jQuery in order to give a better understanding of what I want to achieve.

```
var quotes = document.getElementsByClassName("quotes");

 document.getElementById("generate").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
  quotes.style.visibility = "hidden";
  quotes[random].style.visibility = "visible";
  //$('.quotes').hide().eq(random).show();
});
```

I wish to display a random paragraph tag when I run the code. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`quotes` is an [array-like](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) object and therefore doesn't have a `style` property.

You can instead loop through each in the array and change it's `visibility` property.

Furthermore you can use a ternary operator within the loop to set the 1 item to visible.

```
for(var i = 0; i < quotes.length; i++){
   quotes[i].style.visibility = (i==random) ? "visible" : "hidden";
}
```

Strictly speaking if you wish to copy your jQuery implementation into VanillaJS then it is the `display` property you should be changing, not `visibility`.

```
for(var i = 0; i < quotes.length; i++){
   quotes[i].style.display = (i==random) ? "block" : "none";
}
```

**Working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/1cog9t3c/1/**

---

```js
var quotes = document.getElementsByClassName("quotes");

 document.getElementById("generate").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
  for(var i = 0; i < quotes.length; i++){
      quotes[i].style.display = (i==random) ? "block" : "none";
   }
});
```

```html
<div class="quotes">
test
</div>
<div class="quotes">
test 2
</div>
<div class="quotes">
test 3
</div>

<button id="generate">
gen
</button>
```

Comment: I found this the clearest of the replies. Can I ask about the '= (i==random) ? "block" : "none";' part of the code? Little beyond my current understanding...

Also, thank you!

Comment: @JoshuaPP It's a ternary operator :). It's basically shorthand for `if (i==random) { return "block"; } else { return "none"; }`

Comment: Thanks so much! 
However, I have a slightly bigger problem now as I need to reference the selected quote further down in my code e.g. the randomly select quote needs to be selected in my JS. Any ideas how I can do this? Spent a while thinking about it but can't figure it out? Might be deserving of a separate post  though.

EDIT: Think I may need to find a way to select any p tag with the class block (will only be a single paragraph at any given time) in order to achieve this. I can visualise better the way the code works now I have looked at it in action in the dev tools

Comment: Also, here is the full link to my code... might make it easier to visualise what I am trying to do/say: https://codepen.io/Saudade/pen/bgwmNa

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
var quotes = document.getElementsByClassName("quotes");
```

with

```
var quotes=document.getelemetsByid("quotes").innerhtml;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `quotes` is an `HTMLCollection`, so you need to loop over it.

You can use `Array.prototype.forEach.call` to call a function on every element of an array:

```js
var quotes = document.getElementsByClassName("quotes");

document.getElementById("generate").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(quotes, function(quote) {
        quote.style.visibility = "hidden";
    });
    
    quotes[random].style.visibility = "visible";
});
```

```html
<div class="quotes">quote1</div>
<div class="quotes">quote2</div>
<div class="quotes">quote3</div>
<div class="quotes">quote4</div>

<div id="generate">
    Generate
</div>
```